# SML "('a list * int) -> ('a list, boolean)"

Tags: list, tuples, sml

So this is my question: i wanna make a function that takes a list and and int, it then recursively moves through the list, and if it finds an element in the list equal to the int, then it should return the entire list with the element removed, and a boolean indicating wether something was removed. this is what i got so far:

```
fun foo ([], n) = ([],false)
  | foo ((x::xs), n) = if x = n 
                       then (xs,true)
                       else ([x] @ foo(xs,n),false);
```

my idea was to make the function cons the needed elements inside the tuple like this:

```
([x0] @ [x1] @ [x2] @ [xs], true)
```

so is there any way to make this function? keep in mind that it has to stop once it hits the element equal to n, but still retain the rest of the list, and be able to return a boolean. run time is key.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is close to correct logically, but as you know it doesn't type-check because of `[x] @ foo (xs, n)`.  `foo` returns a tuple, which can't be directly appended.  Here's how to fix it:

```
fun foo ([], n) = ([], false)
  | foo (x::xs, n) = if x = n
                     then (xs, true)
                     else let val (xs', tf) = foo (xs, n) in (x::xs', tf) end
```

The `let` is needed to extract the list from the tuple and find out if `n` was found in the tail of the list.  Then we simply put the tuple back together with `x` consed back on to the front.

Comment: What type error are you getting?  This code compiles and runs correctly on my machine, although it does give a warning for using polyEqual.  That is caused by the `x = n` in the `if`.  Since you said that you only care about integers, the easiest way to avoid this is to give `n` and explicit type by changing the start of the function to `fun foo ([], n:int) = ...`.  If that isn't what's causing your error, please copy the entire error message here.

Comment: The logic:  `if x = n` tests to see if the head of the list is equal to the number you want to remove.  If it is, then it simply returns the rest of the list (which is naturally the list with the head removed) and `true`, since it removed the element.  If the head is not equal to `n`, then it tries removing `n` from the remainder of the list with a recursive call to `foo`, storing the return value into the pair `(xs', tf)`.  Finally, we return a new pair `(x::xs, tf)` which simply puts `x` back onto the front of the returned list, because it's not equal to `n` and should remain.